# How do I make a coroutine always runs after another coroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 `IEnumerator` functions:

- `AnimationCoroutine()`: Do a procedural animation (runs each frame).
- `CameraResizeCoroutine()`: Just to resize the camera size smoothly (runs each frame).

Because the animation is using both game objects and UI elements, in every frame I have to get the camera size and match all calculations with it. So inside the `AnimationCoroutine()`, I have some lines of code that calculate some values and it's base on the camera size of the current frame:

```
    while (elapsed <= duration) {
        cameraSize = Camera.main.orthographicSize;
        tmpScale = cameraSize * SIZE_SCALE_TO_CAMERA * Vector3.one;

        process = Mathf.Clamp01(elapsed / duration);
        // ...

        elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
```

The problem is these two doesn't have any order to get called, I mean when the camera is resizing, the animation get called, or vice versa. So in some frames, `AnimationCoroutine()` runs BEFORE `CameraResizeCoroutine()`, because of that, `AnimationCoroutine()` calculations is base on the camera size of the PREVIOUS FRAME, and made some weird things :D

How do I make the `AnimationCoroutine()` always run after `CameraResizeCoroutine()` in every frame no matter the call order? I mean something like LateUpdate().

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not just call the one from within the other? Of course you need to prevent the former to be called by unity in this case, however no-one forces you to have both methods be called by unity.

Comment: Why not call a `CameraResize` method from the `AnimationCoroutine` passing the value so it runs every frame that the  `AnimationCoroutine` using the correct value without the need for the 2nd `Coroutine`?

Comment: "These two doesn't have any order to get called", I don't mean Unity calls, but I call it, when there is an event that needs camera resize, I StartCoroutine(CameraResizeCoroutine()), when there is an event that needs animation, I call StartCoroutine(AnimationCoroutine()), these two functions don't have any order to StartCoroutine(). The location of these two functions in script is also very far, separated classes, separated folders.

Comment: okay, let's start differently: are these two methods allways called in combination, or are the scenarios in which only one of them is called, while the other is not?

Comment: I think the 2nd one is closer to my case. For example: at time 10s, somewhere in my game, an event trigger the StartCoroutine(CameraResizeCoroutine()), and this coroutine will be end at the time 15s, but at time 12s, in somewhere else, another event trigger StartCoroutine(AnimationCoroutine()). Then the problem happens from 12s-15s

Answer (score 1):

If a coroutine depends on other coroutine's execution, you can yield it inside of another coroutine, or start it from within the other coroutine:

`yield` method - runs sequentially

```cs
private IEnumerator MasterRoutine() {
    while(/* condition */) {
        // ... some code

        yield return SlaveRoutine(); // this will wait for slave to finish
    }
}

private IEnumerator SlaveRoutine() {
    // ... some code
}
```

`StartCoroutine()` method - runs in "parallel"

```cs
private IEnumerator MasterRoutine() {
    while(/* condition */) {
        // ... some code

        yield return null;
    }
    
    StartCoroutine(SlaveRoutine())  // this will run after the wile loop, but independently of the master coroutine
}

private IEnumerator SlaveRoutine() {
    // ... some code
}
```