# Why is my coroutine called after my normal function, even though my coroutine is called first?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why is my co-routine called after my normal function, even though my co-routine is called first

I tried to call `CheckClass()` first then put the return value to the `checkClassList`, then I call my `JoinClass()` function, but no matter how I put it, the `JoinCLass()` is always called first.

This is my function:

```cs
public void OnJoinClass()
{
    StartCoroutine(checkClass(studentId));
    print(classCheckList.Length);
    JoinClass(studentId, InputClassCode.text);
    print("succes");
}
```

This is my `CheckClass()` co-routine:

```cs
IEnumerator checkClass(string id_Student)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("addStudentId", id_Student);

    WWW w = new WWW(URL5, form);

    yield return w;
    string classchecklist = w.text;

    classCheckList = classchecklist.Split(";");
    print(classCheckList.Length);
}
```

And this is the `JoinCLass()` function:

```cs
public void JoinClass(string id_Student, string id_Class)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < classCheckList.Length; i++)
    {
        print(classCheckList[i] + "==" + id_Class + "\n");
        if (classCheckList[i] == id_Class)
        {
            print(classCheckList[i]);
            isJoined = true;
        }
    }

    if (!isJoined)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("addStudentId", id_Student);
        form.AddField("addClassId", id_Class);

        WWW www = new WWW(URL4, form);
    }
    else
    {
        print("Sudah Masuk Kelas");
    }
}
```

Comment: name is `StartCoroutine` not `AwaitCoroutine`

Comment: Simply put, you start the coroutine. This will branche off asynchronously and run at the same time the program is already making its way down the function where the coroutine is started. If you want results from the coroutine you will have to yield it. take a look at the [official docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html). When using asynchronous/ coroutines it is very important to understand the basics of asynchronous programming.

Comment: Adding to what @Roe said: Have in mind that Coroutines are only pseudo asynchronous - meaning they still run on the same thead

Answer (score 2):

The first coroutine does get called first, but since you're yielding: `yield return w`, it will yield after the request has finished. Meanwhile, your code continues running synchronously and it starts another coroutine, which finishes before the WWW request is fulfilled.

If you're using only one coroutine, simply call `JoinClass` inside the coroutine, after it yields the result.

```cs
IEnumerator checkClass(string id_Student)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("addStudentId", id_Student);


    WWW w = new WWW(URL5, form);

    yield return w;
    string classchecklist = w.text;

    classCheckList = classchecklist.Split(";");
    print(classCheckList.Length);

    if (/* condition is met */) {
       JoinClass(studentId, InputClassCode.text);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it is possible to yield a second coroutine inside the first one and remove the `StartCoroutine` call for the second one in the `Start` method.

Check my answer here on how to handle "master" and "slave" coroutines:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76374713/7131671

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of that, you call "JoinClass" method right after starting "checkClass" coroutine. But "checkClass" coroutine uses "yield" and it may take a little time to complete (certainly will not complete immediately).

So you should call "JoinClass" after being sure that "checkClass" has completed. Maybe you can call JoinClass inside checkClass method like that.

```
public void OnJoinClass()
{
    StartCoroutine(checkClass(studentId));
}

IEnumerator checkClass(string id_Student)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("addStudentId", id_Student);


    WWW w = new WWW(URL5, form);

    yield return w;
    string classchecklist = w.text;

    classCheckList = classchecklist.Split(";");
    print(classCheckList.Length);

    JoinClass(studentId, InputClassCode.text);
    print("succes");
}



public void JoinClass(string id_Student, string id_Class)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < classCheckList.Length; i++)
    {
        print(classCheckList[i] + "==" + id_Class + "\n");
        if (classCheckList[i] == id_Class)
        {
            print(classCheckList[i]);
            isJoined = true;
        }
    }

    if (!isJoined)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("addStudentId", id_Student);
        form.AddField("addClassId", id_Class);


        WWW www = new WWW(URL4, form);
    }
    else
    {
        print("Sudah Masuk Kelas");
    }
    
}
```